# Making a STL Queue of pointer types in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, queue

I can't quite seem to figure out why this doesn't work. I tried to make a queue of pointer types and it failed. I have a class Room, and I want to make a queue of pointers to Room.. so I did:

```
queue<*Room> bfsRooms;
```

this gave me the error:

> `*' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Does this mean it is impossible to make a STL queue of pointers?

Comment: what's Q of pointers ? do you mean const of pointers?

Comment: Please show us your code. Note that `queue<Room>` is not a queue of pointers, unless Room is a `typedef` to a pointer type.

Comment: @billz is "const of pointers" the collective noun?

Comment: @Caribou lolz, I think so... and i like it =P

Comment: Put `*` after `Room` not before it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it should be fine, you should really link the exact code and exact error so we can help you better.

That said a queue of pointers would look something like this:

```
 Room r;
 std::queue<Room*> rooms;
 rooms.push(&r);
```

EDIT: it is worth noting that if these pointer own their objects they point to you should really encapsulate the pointer in a smart pointer, something like:

```
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Room>> rooms;
```

This abide by the RAII principle and will automatically clean up resources.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm a C++ noob and didn't realize it should be Room* instead of *Room, that fixed my problem. I feel dumb haha.

Comment: @ThomasColgrove if you can mark it correct if it helped so it can help others in the future